# Caption package error

Tags: captions

Since today I am getting an error message when I use the caption package.

This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figure.jpg}
\caption{caption }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error messages:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \@makecaption already defined. 
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.

! LaTeX Error: Command \@makecaption already defined.
Or name `\end... illegal`, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.

! Undefined control sequence.
\caption@beginex ...tion@begin {#1}\caption@iflof
{\def \caption@tempa {#2}}...
l.12 \caption{this is caption}
```

I am using MikTex 2.9 for windows and I was using the 2012 version of the caption package. I then uploaded to a newer version but it didn't solve the problem.

The file list:

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
  latin1.def    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
 amssymb.sty    2009/06/22 v3.00
 caption.sty    2006/01/12 v3.0i Customising captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2012/01/12 v1.4b caption3 kernel (AR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Comment: This 'works for me', so I suspect a version issue. Can you try adding `\listfiles` to your input, keep going past the errors and edit the resulting `*File list*` from the log into the question.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I updated my post with the file list.

Comment: Works for me without problem in an up-to-date miktex 2.9. And my caption version is newer. If you have multiuser installation: Make sure that you did run the update manager in admin *and* user mode. Also make sure that you are not using some older versions stored in your document folder or a local texmf tree.

Comment: You are using old package versions; for example, in my system (TeX Live2012) I have  `caption.sty    2013/02/03 v3.3-65 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2013/02/03 v1.5-62 caption3 kernel (AR)`

Comment: `caption.sty` and `caption3.sty` must fit into one another, therefore both are always offered as a bundle. But you have an own blend of the `caption` package bundle on your computer, one part (`caption.sty`) from 2006, but the other part (`caption3.sty`) from 2012. This is doomed to fail.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: Make that an answer, please.